# Solving date issue in r

Tags: r

I have a data frame of 700000 rows having numerous date formats like

10/15/2014 (10 is month, 15 is date and 2014 is year)
10-12-14 (10 is date, 12 is month and 14 is year)
4/18/2015 (4 is month 18 is date and 2015 is year)
31-03-16 (31 is date 03 is month and 16 is year)

There can be other formats but this is a sample which I could see.

Can I get a function to find out unique date formats and apply a similar date format to all to convert them in a single dd-mm-yyyy format.

Comment: Going to be difficult as will be ambiguous dates - is 01-02-2016 the first of February or second of January.

Comment: (just to emphasize, 11/12 days in every month are ambiguous, so 36% of your data would be junk if there's no consistent format)

Comment: How do you know 10/12/14 is date/month/year and not month/date/year?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give `parse_date_time` a try and tweak it:

```
library(lubridate)
x <- c("10/15/2014", "10-12-14", "4/18/2015", "31-03-16")
parse_date_time(x, c("mdY", "dmy"))
# [1] "2014-10-15 UTC" "2014-12-10 UTC" "2015-04-18 UTC" "2016-03-31 UTC"
```

Comment: how do I use gsub or grepl to filter out "10-02-14" kind of date formats at once in my data frame. I think this can help me with specific dates at one place and I can convert them into same formats

Comment: `grep("\\d{2}-\\d{2}-\\d{2}", x, invert = T, value = TRUE)` filters out `"10-02-14"`, `"09-02-10"` etc . See help at `?\`regular expression\``.